# EJB 3.0 Access two databases from single session bean EJB 3.0

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I want to access two databases from a single stateless session bean in EJB 3.0. I have created a session bean in which I have declared two entity managers, in order to communicate with the two database. The entity managers are defined in this way in my stateless session bean:

```
@PersistenceContext (unitName="abc") private EntityManager manager;
@PersistenceContext (unitName="xyz") private EntityManager manager1;
```

Using the first entity manager I am getting data from one database, which I then insert into the second database, using the second entity manager. My problem now is that I am able declare both entity managers but I am not able to use them both at the same time. I have to comment out using one of them or else I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
Caused by: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not enlist in transaction on
entering meta-aware object!;
  - nested throwable:" "Caused by:  
    org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object"
    "Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable:"
```

Comment: You will most likely need to use an XA datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Each method in a stateless session bean gets a transaction.  If you're accessing more than one database within the method you must have xa datasources, not tx.

I've run into this before and there is a work-around.  Create separate stateless session beans for each database, then turn off transactions for your original method in the original stateless session bean:

```
@EJB(mappedName="com.abc.AbcManager")
private AbcManager abcManager;

@EJB(mappedName="com.xyz.XyzManager")
private XyzManager xyzManager;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public MyResponse getMyData(MyRequest request) throws MyException {
    Collection<Data> data = abcManager.getData();

    xyzManager.storeData(data);

    return null;
}
```

The methods on the new session beans will create their own transactions but you can still have a single stateless session bean coordinating the other two.